# Get-WFOutboundCertificate : The underlying connection was closed

Tags: sharepoint-server, certificate

I am in process to update certificate in SharePoint 2016 server where one of the steps is to run the **Set-WFNextOutboundCertificateReference** workflow manager PowerShell command.

Before that, while running the below command:

```
  Get-WFOutboundCertificate -ServiceURI https://SERVER:12290/
```

Getting the the below error:

**Get-WFOutboundCertificate : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TL**

Could someone please help me on this.